# How to check lowercase in indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here diseaseList is an array .

```
for(var i=0;i<_list.length;i++)
{
    if($scope.diseaseList.indexOf(_list[i].disease) != -1){
        _list[i].favorite = true;
    }else{
        _list[i].favorite = false;
    }
}
```

I want to do somthing like this

```
if($scope.diseaseList.toLoweCase().indexOf(_list[i].disease.toLoweCase()) != -1){
```

but it is throwing error as `$scope.diseaseList` is an array .I can remove `indexOf` and use one more loop but that I dont want to do .Any other option 
please suggest.

Comment: `angular.lowercase(_list[i].disease);` ?

Comment: convert the array to use lowercase

Comment: If you want to call .toLowerCase() on array, than you need to monkey-patch the array prototype first ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays don't have `toLowerCase` (note that in your code there is a typo: missing `r`) function. But you can use the `map` function and return the lowercase values. It works like this:

```
["Foo", "BaR"].map(function (c) { return c.toLowerCase(); });
// => ["foo", "bar"]
```

In your code, this can be applied like below:

```
if($scope.diseaseList.map(function (c) {
    return c.toLowerCase();
   }).indexOf(_list[i].disease.toLowerCase()) != -1) { ... }
```

And additionally, you can remove `!= -1` and change it to use the bitwise operator:

```
if(~$scope.diseaseList.map(function (c) {
    return c.toLowerCase();
   }).indexOf(_list[i].disease.toLowerCase())) { ... }
```

[**@Tushar**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) has another interesting solution for converting an array of strings to lowercase:

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase.apply(arr).split(',');
```

Comment: Should be `return c.toLowerCase();` (note the extra `r` to `Lower`).

Comment: `String.prototype.toLowerCase.apply(arr).split(',');` Can also be used

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. Added it to answer. :) Not sure how it works across the browsers (if I'm not wrong there were some problems on IE in stringifying arrays). But it's cute.

Comment: @IonicăBizău You can also use `arr.map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase));` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006222/how-to-pass-the-method-defined-on-prototype-to-array-map-as-callback