# How to pass the method defined on prototype to Array.map as callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have an array

```
var arr = [' A ', ' b ', 'c'];
```

and I want to `trim` the spaces from each of the element from array.

It can be done by using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as

```
arr.map(function(el) {
    return el.trim();
});
```

I'm curious about passing the `trim`/`toLowerCase` function directly to the `map` as callback function, like [arr.map(Math.max.apply.bind(Math.max, null));](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679435/2025923) to get the maximum element from each subarray or [arr.map(Number);](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32964709/2025923) to cast each element to Number.

I've tried

```
arr.map(String.prototype.trim.apply);
```

but it is throwing error

> Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function

I expect that `String.prototype.trim.apply` should be called for each element in the array with the context set to the element from array(passed to `apply`);

I've also tried different combinations of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) with no success.

1. **Why** the function on prototype cannot be referenced when using `map`
2. **How** function can be passed as parameter to `map`

Comment: I'm confused as to why arr.map(function... works whereas arr.map(String... throws "arr is not defined."

Comment: In Firefox it says “TypeError: `Function.prototype.apply` called on incompatible `undefined`”.

Comment: var f = String.prototype.trim.call; f(' 3 '); throws error, even though String.prototype.trim.call(' 3' ) works and typeof f === 'function'. No idea why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
arr.map(String.prototype.trim.call.bind(String.prototype.trim));
```

`call` uses `this` internally, which must point to the `trim` function to work properly in this case. Simply passing `String.prototype.trim.call` would leave `call` unbound to any method, resulting in the `this` value pointing to `window` instead.

> It works, but when used apply instead of call it throws error,
>   arr.map(String.prototype.trim.apply.bind(String.prototype.trim));

The problem is that `map` will pass 2 arguments, the item and the index. Therefore it ends up calling something like `'String.prototype.trim.apply('test', 0)` which fails since the second argument must be an array.

> one more thing [' A ', ' B ',
>   'c'].map(String.prototype.trim.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase));,
>   in this, I've used trim.call and passed toLowerCase as context then
>   why we need trim here, why trim is not called

When using `call.bind` the path that you chose to access the `call` function reference becomes irrelevant. The function that will get called is the one that is bound.

If you want to compose functions together you will need a different approach:

```
var call = Function.prototype.call,
    trim = call.bind(String.prototype.trim),
    toLowerCase = call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase),
    trimAndLowerCase = pipelineFrom(trim, toLowerCase);

[' TeST '].map(trimAndLowerCase);

function pipelineFrom(fn1, fn2) {
    return function (val) {
        return fn2(fn1(val));
    };
}
```

However at this point you're better off with:

```
arr.map(function (val) {
    return val.trim().toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: It works, but when used `apply` instead of `call` it throws error, `arr.map(String.prototype.trim.apply.bind(String.prototype.trim));`

Comment: one more thing `[' A ', ' B ', 'c'].map(String.prototype.trim.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase));`, in this, I've used `trim.call` and passed `toLowerCase` as context then why we need `trim` here, why trim is not called

Comment: @Tushar `trim` will not get called because you only used it as a shortcut to get a reference to the `call` function. The function that will be called is `toLowerCase`. For instance, you could have done `Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase)` and it would also work. How you get a reference to the `call` function becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

This works, it sure is long-winded though:

```
var t = String.prototype.trim.call.bind(String.prototype.trim);
arr.map(t);
```

Because it's longwinded there are [blog posts](http://www.2ality.com/2011/11/uncurrying-this.html) and [modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uncurrythis) devoted to uncurrying, which is what you are trying to do here.

I did [ask about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23482982/1339987) here once...

Comment: It works, but when used `apply` instead of `call` it throws error, `arr.map(String.prototype.trim.apply.bind(String.prototype.trim));`

Comment: one more thing `[' A ', ' B ', 'c'].map(String.prototype.trim.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase));`, in this, I've used `trim.call` and passed `toLowerCase` as context then why we need `trim` here, why trim is not called

Answer (score 1):

I use a small `method` function for this kind of thing -

```js
const method = f => f.call.bind(f)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(method("".trim)))
```

Another option is to define `trim` in advance -

```js
const method = f => f.call.bind(f)
   
const trim = method("".trim)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim))
```

```js
[
  "alice",
  "bob",
  "charlie"
]
```

Some methods take additional arguments. `method` works with that too -

```js
const method = f => f.call.bind(f)
   
const trim = method("".trim)
const replace = method("".replace)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim).map(v => replace(v, "e", "E")))
```

```js
[
  "alicE",
  "bob",
  "charliE"
]
```

You can rewrite `method` to enable [**tacit programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) (aka point-free style) -

```js
const method = f => (...args) => data =>
  f.apply(data, args)
   
const trim = method("".trim)()
const upper = method("".toUpperCase)()
const replace = method("".replace)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim).map(replace(/[aeiou]/g, upper)))
```

```js
[
  "AlIcE",
  "bOb",
  "chArlIE"
]
```

Finally we can make `method` smarter to analyze `f.length` to determine if more arguments should be supplied by the caller -

```js
const method = f => 
  f.length == 0
    ? data => f.call(data)
    : (...args) => data => f.apply(data, args)
   
const trim = method("".trim)
const upper = method("".toUpperCase)
const replace = method("".replace)

const list = [
  "   alice    ",
  "  bob  ",
  "    charlie  "
]

console.log(list.map(trim).map(replace(/[aeiou]/g, upper)))
```

```js
[
  "AlIcE",
  "bOb",
  "chArlIE"
]
```